# Возможно ли сделать в git diff подсветку синтаксиса, как в vim?

Tags: linux, git, vim

Сравниваю два коммита, но весь код белым цветом.

Можно ли сравнить коммиты, включив подсветку синтаксиса?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

выполните вначале команду

```
git config --global color.ui auto
```

после этого снова пробуйте сделать дифф. (другие команды также будут "разукрашены" [как все настроить под себя](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44266/how-to-colorize-output-of-git)).

Answer (score 1):

Также можно воспользоваться командой `git difftool`. Её плюс — есть также подсветка синтаксиса, а файлы показываются параллельно.

Answer (score 0):

Так подсветка синтаксиса точно будет как в *vim*:

```
git config --global diff.tool vimdiff
```

И для удобства:

```
git config --global alias.dt difftool
```

Вызов `git dt`.